# CSS Animated Gradient Header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a animated gradient to my header class.  For some reason I am not able to get this to work.

I'm trying to do this but not to the body, just the header. https://www.gradient-animator.com/

What's going on here?  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

The HTML, CSS

```css
.business-header {
    background: linear-gradient(50deg, #282466, #ffc500);
    height: 400px;
   
    
    -webkit-animation: test 2s ease infinite;
            animation: test 2s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0%{background-position:51% 0%}
    50%{background-position:20% 100%}
    100%{background-position:51% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes test {
    0%{background-position:51% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:51% 0%}
}
@keyframes test { 
    0%{background-position:51% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:51% 0%}
}
```

```html
<header class="business-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="tagline"></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dde1b3x0/1/)

```
.business-header {
   background: linear-gradient(270deg, #a4ffe8, #092f25);
   background-size: 400% 400%;
   -webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
   -moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
   animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   height:400px;
}
```

You did not mention the background size.. that was the problem

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had also just figured this out. It's been a long night.